# Is Ubuntu Touch a separate distribution or the same one?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, arm

I would like to install the latest Ubuntu Touch on a [2013 Nexus 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_(2013)) tablet. Which version should I be looking for: the regular Ubuntu (for ARM platform) or a separate Ubuntu Touch?

I understand that Ubuntu Touch is in frantic development, but I would like to be able to keep track which one is which. I can see the following images:

- [Ubuntu 14.09 RTM, daily-preinstalled](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/ubuntu-rtm/14.09/daily-preinstalled/)
- [Ubuntu Touch 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn) Daily Build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/)
- [Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn) Daily Build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/), but only i386 and amd64; no ARM. Does it mean that ARM variant has moved to one of the first two links?

Which is the right one to download to run on a Nexus 7 tablet?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Touch is a mobile version of the developed by Canonical UK Ltd and Ubuntu Community. It is designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablet computers with only supported x86 and ARM CPU architecture.

If you have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus or Google Nexus 4 smartphone, or a Nexus 7 or Nexus 10 tablet, you can download and install a touch-friendly version of Ubuntu on your device.

You'll need a computer running Ubuntu, a decent internet connection, and the ability to accept all responsibility of something goes horribly wrong. But here's basically how the process works.

It's a good idea to make a backup or your device before you start. If you've already rooted your device and installed a custom recovery, you can use ClockworkMod, TWRP, or a similar program to do that.

You can follow installation tutorial from [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation) and also here is step by step [Run the latest Ubuntu Touch on your Nexus device](http://www.techradar.com/news/mobile-computing/how-to-install-ubuntu-touch-on-the-google-nexus-7-1142801/1) tutorial

Comment: So it is separate, though AFAIK Canonical is going to converge it back to the main Ubuntu at some point in the future, right? Where is the right one to download: I've found '14.09' and '14.10'?  And, I believe, that's why the ARM platform images disappeared from the 'regular' Ubuntu: they were dubbed Ubuntu Touch.

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov I have updated my answer. check please.

Comment: Thanks for expanding your answer in response to my expanded question! Can you confirm or deny this: did Ubuntu Touch spin off from the regular Ubuntu? Are they going to converge? I would like (every) regular flavor of Ubuntu to be touch-friendly, but in the meantime I'm eager to try whatever is available.

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov See [Touch Developer Preview FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/FAQ) and for more [Hands-on with Ubuntu Touch 14.04](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/04/hands-on-with-ubuntu-touch-14-04-coming-along-but-miles-to-go/). thank you

Comment: Which version are they testing in the _Hands-on_? I don't see any ARM release for 14.04.

Comment: Did you read this http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/04/ubuntu-14-04-will-power-first-commercially-available-ubuntu-tablets/